# C++ obtaining the type of a constructor

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I'm trying to deduce the types of a class's constructor's parameters. I've succeeded in getting the parameter types for member methods but my approach fails for constructors because it relies on getting the type of a pointer to the member method.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

// Some type with a constructor
struct foo {
    foo(int, double) {}
    void test(char, char) {};
};

// Extract the first parameter
template<class T>
struct func_traits {};

template<class Return, class Type, class ... Params>
struct func_traits<Return(Type::*)(Params...)> {
    using params = std::tuple<Params...>;
};

// Get the parameters for foo::test
using test_type = decltype(&foo::test);
using test_params = typename func_traits<test_type>::params;
static_assert(std::is_same<test_params, std::tuple<char, char>>::value, "Not the right tuple");

// Get the parameters for foo::foo
using ctor_type = decltype(&foo::foo);  // Forbidden
using ctor_type = typename func_traits<ctor_type>::params;
static_assert(std::is_same<ctor_type, std::tuple<int, double>>::value, "Not the right tuple");
```

It's forbidden to obtain the address of a constructor, but I only want to know the type that pointer *would have*.

- Is there another way of determining the type of such a pointer?
- Otherwise, is there another way of getting the type of a constructor?

Comment: Does your existing code work with overloaded functions?

Comment: @KerrekSB It works if you specify the overload, but in that case you already know the parameters so it's moot. I assumed I would encounter a problem with overloads, but I haven't gotten there yet.

Comment: Is good enough for you a type traits that confirm (or negate) if a type can be constructed with a given signature?

Comment: As it stands, the answer is no. Constructors don't have names and cannot have their addresses taken. There was mention of an idea to propose a magic type trait that would expose a class's constructors as a set of function call operator overloads, but that has not (yet) made it anywhere.

Comment: @max66 No, I am trying to deduce the arguments. It isn't sufficient to verify that the signature matches.

Comment: With the way C++ standard considers a Constructor as a very privileged *function*. It is practically impossible. - It has no return type. has no address, and the only way its *name*(assuming it had) is even useful is in a delegating constructors and perhaps inheriting constructor syntax...

Comment: @WhiZTiM: You cannot *name* a constructor. The using declaration you have in mind is just syntax (just like how you declare constructors).

Comment: Hello. Did you find any way to extract parameters' types from constructor? I'm currently breaking my head with the same task. It's probably possible, as Boost.DI most probably does it somehow.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov I have not found a way to achieve this. It has to somehow be provided by the type. I opted for specializing a trait.

Comment: If anyone still wonders, I left my answer down below how to obtain constructor parameter types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to refer to a constructor as a function. The standard very explicitly states that constructors have no names. You can't take the address of a constructor.

An alternative might be to require of any type to be used with some machinery, that it has an associated traits type that provides tuples or something corresponding to the constructors.

Before we got language support for `decltype` as I recall the Boost functionality for finding the result type of a function relied on a registration scheme for possible types.

Answer (score 8):

There is a solution that allows you to obtain constructor parameters types.

Note: it finds the first ctor having unambiguous and shortest set of parameters.

Look at my example here: https://godbolt.org/z/FxPDgU

In your example, the statement `refl::as_tuple<foo>` will result in `std::tuple<int, double>`. Once you have this tuple type, you can whatever you want, including `foo` type instantiation.

The code above is based on a solution for determining types used for aggregate-init extended to handle user-defined ctors.

Related materials:

1. http://alexpolt.github.io/type-loophole.html

   https://github.com/alexpolt/luple/blob/master/type-loophole.h

   by Alexandr Poltavsky, http://alexpolt.github.io
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UlNUNxLtBI0

   Better C++14 reflections - Antony Polukhin - Meeting C++ 2018