# How to deduce types of the class constructor's arguments, from the class type alone

Tags: c++, templates

In template metaprogramming, there is a trick:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct my_struct {};

template <typename... T1, typename... Ts>
struct my_struct <std::tuple<T1, Ts...>>
{
    // Tuple is "unpacked"
    // I can freely work on 'T1' & 'Ts' types (through recursion) in this scope.
    using type = T1;
};
```

I was hoping that a similar trick exists for member functions (especially constructor):

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct my_struct {};

// specialisation for case when type 'T' has 'T(U1, Us...)' ctor.
template <typename T, typename U1, typename... Us>
struct my_struct <
    decltype(T::T(
        std::declval<U1>(), 
        std::declval<Us>()...
    ))
>
{
    using type = U1;
};
```

unfortunately, this results in an error:

> template parameter "U1" & parameter pack "Us" is not used in or cannot be deduced from the template argument list of class template "my_struct"

Is there any way to get the types of T's ctor arguments?

---

I need the above because I have a function `func<T>()` which must be "specialized" (/"overloaded") for a situation when Type `T` has `T(std::initializer_list</* ??? */>)` constructor.

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct get_init_list_type_from_T_ctor 
{
    // magic happens here
};

template<typename T>
using has_init_list_ctor = std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_constructible_v<
        T,
        std::initializer_list<
            typename get_init_list_type_from_T_ctor<T>::type
        >
    >
>;

// version for T with initialization list ctor
template<
    typename T,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_detected_v<has_init_list_ctor, T>
    >
>
void func() {
    //... 
}

// version for T without initialization list ctor
template<
    typename T,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<
        !std::is_detected_v<has_init_list_ctor, T>
    >
>
void func() {
    //... 
}
```

Comment: C++17 has [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), but this might be a different problem.

Comment: If you have a specific list of what the constructor's arguments are, you can SFINAE by that. Otherwise, no, I don't see a way to deduce a constructor's arguments. What if there are overloaded constructors? What if the constructors themselves have a variadic parameter pack? This is obviously un-possible. This requires full-blown reflection which, of course, C++ does not have.

Comment: The “trick” you show is a partial specialization—it’s not some sort of generic unpacking mechanism.  I don’t know what that `decltype` incantation *would* mean if it worked; you can’t refer to a constructor that way, and you can’t deduce from an *expression* at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ obtaining the type of a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623899/c-obtaining-the-type-of-a-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to enforce a specific constructor signature in C++.

However, if the type of the initializer list is fixed, you can still utilize SFINAE by calling the constructor with the required arguments:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct has_init_list_ctor
    : std::is_constructible<T, std::initializer_list<U>>
{
};

template <typename T, typename U>
inline constexpr bool has_init_list_ctor_v = has_init_list_ctor<T, U>::value;
```

This won't work if you don't know the type of the initializer list.  We have to wait for the Reflection TS.  If that is the case, I can't think of how this can possibly be useful, though.